# They sure worked me!

Tags: phrase-meaning

Someone returned home from a travel and said:

> "They sure worked me!"

What does "work somebody" mean? Or what can this sentence possibly convey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "They sure worked me!"

Here, the definition of "work" is

> ... to make a person or animal do a job (Cambridge).

*If you work someone, you make them spend time and effort doing a particular activity or job* ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/work)). It's definition 19.

> They're working me too hard. I'm too old for this. [VERB noun adverb/preposition]

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall ever hearing "They sure worked me!" by itself being used previously, and a Bing search for [`"they sure worked me"`](https://cn.bing.com/search?q=%22they%20sure%20worked%20me%22) doesn't show up much.

#### Possibility 1

I think the most likely interpretation is that the subject is the victim of a long-term scam while traveling.  I didn't find a solid reference for this, but when a con artist is trying to trick someone using a long-term strategy, it's sometimes referred to as "working them".  For example:

> Unlike short-cons, romance scams involve **working someone** for money over an extended period.
>   <sub>[Highya](https://www.highya.com/articles-guides/romance-scams-that-target-solo-tourists?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=e4cbf1e2e575f93b8666cb33015d20ea25fb4f65-1576508135-0-AWTxRZPG__KJqkywG1sXyMj1prkDM0eRTDpjXnk7xtTVWQdu2hoRlOxmpO875XfNqtByA6rr_0-Eg1LY3y9Gbz9SHL02BOsYImYxS6FuAZ2OiIj1hesubiBkAN6tNIhBEe0u0Nxsp8SASBCi8APSEHMAEffdr7INFsSDrga5CE_szM3aGsJ-n9SH1_vU23nak7q8r2cRyVJn2DlhN4nELIml-C-YfiaG4fqLnt-2uibOpyFhHUnsmK6dKCrEWdZ1d8LFn_g63V1_cqF072Ofo3XmcE5rtT-TXPIt_4kyAQIvp9RFZSfqQH4VJzDbvQ4mC3_V8TJg8MGGBvSAUkYllhY)</sub>
>
> The ones with the scam artists, the con men **working their mark**, the grift, the con, the flim flam, the hustle, the bamboozle.
>   <sub>[Shmoop](https://www.shmoop.com/finance-glossary/ponzi-scheme.html)</sub>

In this sense, I would interpret "They sure worked me!" as meaning the scammers put a lot of effort into their scam (i.e., it was an elaborate scam), the victim was not particularly suspicious at the time, and the scammers succeeded or nearly succeeded.

#### Possibility 2

It's is a shortened form of the idiom:

> They sure worked me to death.

where "worked to death" means:

> To make someone or oneself work too hard or for excessively long hours.
>   <sub>[The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/work+(someone)%2F(oneself)+to+death)</sub>

(Alternatively, there's also [worked to the bone](https://www.interglot.com/dictionary/en/en/translate/work%20oneself%20to%20the%20bone).)

It refers to a situation where you are required (e.g., by a boss or a spouse) to do a large amount of exhausting work.  This might be suitable after a long and arduous work trip.

#### Possibility 3

It's a shortened version of the idiom:

> They sure worked me over.

where "worked over" means:

> 1. to threaten, intimidate, or beat someone.
> 2. to give someone's body a thorough examination or treatment.
>      <sub>[The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/work+over)</sub>

This might be suitable after being robbed while traveling.  (In my opinion, this is not very likely.)

Comment: For Possibility 2 I prefer AIQ's answer; “worked to death” is needlessly specific.  Otherwise, good job.